# Wiki Markup - link to relative path

Tags: wiki, dokuwiki

With wiki markup is it possible to link to a relative path?

eg:

```
[../rel/path Link Text]
```

I am using DokuWiki.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Possible solution for DokuWiki

A post in the DokuWiki User Forum ["Relative links in wikipages"](https://forum.dokuwiki.org/post/11922) mentions `this` tag.

> It gives a path to the wiki root, so a link like this one
>   `[[this>../../VolD/Projects/]]`
>   can link to some page outside the wiki folder without using a full URL.

See also the official documentation: https://www.dokuwiki.org/interwiki

---

*The rest of this answer was written before I knew that the question was about DokuWiki. I'll leave it for future reference.*

### The problem if you're using MediaWiki

In a wiki, it can be ambiguous to use relative paths because it is common to rewrite URLs. Let's take Wikipedia as an example. When you access http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page, you're not looking at a document called `Main_Page` in `/wiki`. Instead, it is `/w/index.php` that does the work, as you can see from http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Main_Page returning the same output. So, relative URLs will introduce an ugly ambiguity here. Relative from where? (See also http://yoast.com/relative-urls-issues/) As the rewritten URL can be anything, it won't be smart to rely on relative paths.

### Workaround for MediaWiki

I suspect that the reason you want to use a relative path is because you want to link to a file on the same server, but is not managed within the wiki's database. In that case, you can use the [magic word](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aMagic_words) `{{SERVERNAME}}`.

```
[http://{{SERVERNAME}}/rel/path Link text]
```

should give you the link, with `{{SERVERNAME}}` replaced accordingly [(see here)](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aLinks#External_links). 
Taking Wikipedia as an example, `{{SERVERNAME}} = "en.wikipedia.org"`.

So this is not exactly a relative path, but playing around with other magic words such as `{{SCRIPTPATH}}` and `{{STYLEPATH}}` might offer you a solution, depending on what directory you want to access. (For the Wikipedia example, `{{SCRIPTPATH}} = "/w"`.) See http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words#Technical_metadata

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're right in what I wanted to do, but I imagine that `SERVERNAME` is set manually, my problem is that the server will be accessed internally and externally under different effective servernames. I am also using Doku currently which apparently doesn't support SERVERNAME, but your answer is useful and helpful nonetheless, thanks again.

Comment: @JamieKitson You should've said first that you're using DokuWiki! Updated my answer ;-)